# If the Sense Amplifiers structure is the same as an SRAM cell's, why the differential voltage on the bit line gets amplified?

Tags: memory, sram

[image: schematic]

[source](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f429fd0fbf27c28d04fa0b073c1d4d86)

How you can see the structure with 6 transistors of a Sense Amplifier (SA) is the same as a SRAM cell, but this latter causes a little variation on the bitline voltage that the SA will amplify. My question is: then why this does not occur when the SA is activated, but instead it returns a full logic value? I hope I've been clear. Thanks for answering

Comment: First of all, the structure is not exactly the same -- Q5 and Q6 are gating the power to the sense amplifier, not its connections to the bit lines -- and while the topology might be similar, other parameters such as transistor sizes might be quite different. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Ok, except for Q5 and Q6, why does SA increase the voltage on the Bit Lines if it basically is a FlipFlop like an SRAM cell? In other words, why cannot an SRAM cell do the same job and need instead a SA that has a quite identical structure?

Comment: The transistors in the SRAM cell are as small as they possibly can be, in order to maximize the storage density. The transistors in the sense amplifier are typically much larger.

Comment: You've got positive feedback, perhaps designed to be < +1 around the loop, or designed to have loop-gain > +1.